# Unicode Entities are shown in preview, but not in the post

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, markdown-preview

When editing a question and including entities like `&#x25C1;`, they are shown in the preview window. This applies both to hexadecimal entities only.

> [image]

However, in the final post, they're not shown anymore:

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex bug; it was only counting a single hex digit entity as valid, which obviously doesn't make much sense.

[Fixed](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=2f3d224a3fdd79d0fbabd5230baa77d4b421402b) (next build), thanks!